# Changes to one object inadvertently changes another object

Tags: java, list, object

I am trying to work with lists in java and I am getting the following bug in my code(see below). I create a new list object L1 and pass it into function f. Inside function f I create a copy of L1 and name it L2. I do an add operation on L2 and return from the function. After I return the value of L1 has changed. How can this be? From what I understand the scope of L1 does not extend to function f, so L1 cannot be changed in function f. And L2 is a copy of L1 and is its own object so any changes to it should not change L1 either. Can someone explain this to me?

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        List<String> L1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        L1.add("H");
        L1.add("I");
        System.out.println(L1);
        
        f(L1);
        
        System.out.println(L1);
     }
     
     public static void f(List<String> myList){
         List<String> L2 = new ArrayList<String>();
         L2 = myList;
         
         L2.add("!");
         return;
     }
}
```

Which prints out

```
[H, I]
[H, I, !]
```

Comment: you didn't return list and set it to `L1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're creating a new `List` `L2` and then overwriting the reference with `L2 = myList` you should add every `String` value from `myList` instead. Try this.

```java
public static void f(List<String> myList) {
    List<String> L2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str : myList) L2.add(str);
    L2.add("!");
}
```

Since `List` is an object it is passed as reference to method `f` therefore if you do `L2 = myList` you're just saying that `L2` points to the same `List` as `myList`. Read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-31-java-is-strictly-pass-by-value/).

Also you don't have to `return` explicitly in `void` methods.

Finally notice that your method `f` doesn't really do much since it only creates a local new `List` and you're not returning it.

Comment: I actually did this to solve it. I am still confused as to why it would be overwriting it. Aren't they two different objects?
Edit: Ok i will look at link. This is abstracted example from a larger code that actually does something,

Comment: Yes, they are but when you do `L2 = myList` the previous value of `L2` is "discarded". Its simply variable re-assignment.

Comment: Ahh does is this a java specific thing? Or does it occur in other languages?

Comment: It occurs in other languages its normal like a simple `int`. If you have `int a=2, b=3` and you do `b=a` the value 3 is "lost". This happens the same for objects but the variables hold references instead of primitive values.

Answer (score 1):

The list passed in isn’t a copy of a list, it is a reference, it points to the list.

You passed a reference to a list into a method, that reference still points to the original list L1. Then you assign it to L2, and now L2 points to the original list. So no, you’re not changing a second object inadvertently, it’s the same object.

You can pass a reference into a method and it still points to the same object that it points to outside that method.

This is normal for languages that pass references by value. C and JavaScript and Lisp all behave similarly to this.

Comment: Thank you for this. I suspected this but I did not know it was the usual behavior because I am usually passing in a primitive to a function.